# Why am I getting error when implementing mapbox to my project?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, compiler-errors, mapbox

I get this error when trying to implement mapbox to my project. I did every thing following the official mapbox documentation. But when I build the project I get this error. I have no idea why the error occurs. Can anyone please help. This is the logcat error.

```
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.6.2.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > No cached version of com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.6.2 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.6.2 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.6.2 available for offline mode.
      > No cached version of com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.6.2 available for offline mode.

Possible solution:
 - Disable offline mode and rerun the build
```

This is my mapbox kotlin class

```
class mapBoxNav : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var mapView: MapView? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Mapbox.getInstance(this, getString(R.string.access_token))

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_box_nav)
        mapView= findViewById(R.id.mapView)
        mapView?.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        mapView?.getMapAsync{mapboxMap->


        }


    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        mapView?.onStart()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        mapView?.onResume()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        mapView?.onPause()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        mapView?.onStop()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        mapView?.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)


            mapView?.onSaveInstanceState(outState)

    }

    override fun onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory()
        mapView?.onLowMemory()
    }

}
```

This is my line of code I have added to `build.gradle(project)`

```
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()

        maven {
            url'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
            authentication{
                basic(BasicAuthentication)

            }
            credentials{
                username = 'mapbox'
                password = project.properties['MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN']?:""
            }
        }

        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
    }
```

This is my `gradle.build(Module)`dependency

```
 implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.6.2'
```

Comment: Make sure your internet connection is proper at the time of building project.

Comment: Yes my laptop is connected to internet when building the project

Answer (score 0):

```
maven {
            url'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
            authentication{
                basic(BasicAuthentication)

            }
            credentials{
                username = 'mapbox'
                password = project.properties['MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN']?:""
            }
        }
```

the code part above must be added to *settings.gradle*

And you must add dependcy to gradle.build(Module) like that

```
implementation   'com.mapbox.maps:android:10.7.0'
```

Look that link for detailed information.[2021 MapBox Sdk Inst.](https:///medium.com/@alessandro.lombardi.089/setting-up-mapbox-sdk-10-1-0-in-android-studio-2021-5083ca876bdd)